# Finding Relations algebraically

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have selfstudy on this subject and want to know if I am grasping the concept well. Here is the question:

**Let $A=Z^+$, all integers that are positive; Let $R$= relation defined by $aRb$ iff there exists a $n$ in $Z^+$ such that $a=b^n$.
Pick from the following what belongs to R.**

**i) $(1,9)$**

**ii) $(4,16)$**

**iii) $(5,5)$**

**iv) $(49,7)$**

This is how I understand it:

(i) $a=1, b=9$ then $1=9^k$ hence $k=0$ but $0$ is not a member of $Z^+$ hence (i) does not belong to $R$.

(ii) $a=4, b=16$ then $4=16^k$ hence $k=1/2$ but k is not an element in $Z^+ ={1,2,3,4,...}$ hence (ii) does not belong to $R$.
(4,16) cannot be.

(iii) $a=5,b=5$ then $5=5^k$ hence $k = 1$. 1 is member of set $Z^+$ hence (iii) belongs to $R$.

(iv) $a=49, b=7$ then $49=7^k$ hence $k = 2$ is a member of set $Z^+$. Therefore (iv) belongs to $R$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, all of it is correct, except that in (ii) you wrote $\Bbb Z$ when you meant $\Bbb Z^+$, and in (iii) and (iv) you wrote $A$ when you meant $\Bbb Z^+$.